# fuzzy list of items - shuffled, but in strict order

Tags: algorithm, sorting, random, shuffle

I have a list of questions and I need to present each question in a different format.

(a list of N items with M possible permutations for each item).

e.g.

```
questions = [a, b, c]
permutations = [x, y]
permuted_questions = [(a,x), (b,x), (c,x), (a,y), (b,y), (c,y)]
```

Producing a simple list of permutations like above is straightforward. However, 
To make the list more "interesting", I'd like to shuffle it somehow.

The problem is that the list of permutations is strictly *ordered*. i.e. for given item `a`, permutation `(a,x)` should always appear before permutation `(a,y)`.

e.g.

`[(a,x), (b,x), (a,y), (c,x), (b,y), (c,y)]` is a valid shuffle

`[(a,x), (b,y), (a,y), (c,x), (b,x), (c,y)]` is invalid, because `(b,y)` appears before `(b,x)`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply shuffle the questions into any permutation, and then postprocess the list by labelling the first "a" question x, and the second "a" question y, and so on for the other types of question.

e.g.:

```
Construct shuffle:
    (a,x), (b,y), (a,y), (c,x), (b,x), (c,y)

Turn into valid shuffle:
    (a,x), (b,x), (a,y), (c,x), (b,y), (c,y)
```

Example Python code:

```py
from random import shuffle
from itertools import product
from collections import defaultdict
questions = ['a', 'b', 'c']
permutations = ['x', 'y']
Q = list(product(questions,permutations))
shuffle(Q)
D = defaultdict(int) # Keep track of permutation to use for each question
C = []
for q,p in Q:
    C.append( (q,permutations[D[q]]) )
    D[q] += 1
print C
```

Comment: Thanks, but what's the algorithm to turn an invalid shuffle to a valid one? Correct me if I'm wrong, but to me it just "transposes" my problem into another representation...

Comment: I've added some Python code to illustrate an O(n) approach to turn the invalid shuffle into a valid one.

Comment: Thanks so much! ... simple and effective solution.